# document.queryselector of button in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button

How can I get the button that was clicked from inside the ng-click function on buttons inside an ng-repeat tag?

I tried setting the id like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-info ladda-button" type="button" 
    id={{'check_' + 'file.catModel}}
    ng-click="testButton('check_' + file.catModel)"
    data-style="expand-left">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i><span class="ladda-label"> Check</span>
</button>
```

I've tried passing the id to the function then searching with:

```
angular.element
document.getElementById
```

but they are always null.

Is it possible to access the button?

Comment: there is probably a more angular way of doing what you want than accessing dom directly. What are you wanting to do with the button?

Comment: I'm trying to setup a ladda-button loading wheel for each individual button 
https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `$event` property to your click handler.

So, your code will be re-written as (Omitting other attributes for clarity):

```
<button ng-click="testButton('check_' + file.catModel, $event)">Check</button>
```

And in your click handler:

```
$scope.testButton = function (title, event) {
    //event parameter contains all details
    //of the button that invoked this handler
};
```

Comment: This works just like I wanted it to, although, for some reason when I click over the word "Check", the event has the `span` as the `toElement`, so my function doesn't work because it needs a button. would you know how to fix that?

Comment: I just removed the span and it looks the same and works just as I wanted. Thanks